# Design bug: Meta - no separator between answers image upload broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

There's no visual separator on meta between answers. This makes reading difficult. A line or something may be needed.

- Actually this same issue is present on the main site as well. Need some visual separator between answers.

Also.... can't post images.. overlay seems to have a higher z-index than the actual upload box div.)

Comment: Yeah but firebug says its not :/

Comment: I was guessing.. I didn't actually examine the CSS :) It just appears as though the overlay z-index is higher.

Comment: work-around (windows at least) use `space` to activate upload button (it receives initial focus), use `tab` to highlight "ok", `space` to activate button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a more pronounced tiny gap between the answers. the change will be on live after the next production build.